# Create a copy of a subclass, recursively?

Tags: python, class, copy

The class `Event` implements a function `copyFrom(self, event)` and `copy(self)`. The implementation of both methods is simple made cake.

```
class Event(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def copyFrom(self, event):
        self.a = event.a
        self.b = event.b

    def copy(self):
        return Event(self.a, self.b)
```

Now, the subclass `MouseEvent` wants to override both of them. The first method, `copyFrom(self, event)` can be implemented by calling the *super*-method.

```
class MouseEvent(Event):

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        super(Event, self).__init__(a, b)
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

    def copyFrom(self, event):
        super(Event, self).copyFrom(event)
        self.c = event.c
        self.d = event.d
```

But what about `copy(self)` ? Of course, just creating a new object is not hard.

```
    # ...
    def copy(self):
        return MouseEvent(self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d)
```

But what if the `Event` class owns some *private* attributes ? The person that wants to subclass it, does not want to care about them !

```
class Event(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self._aab = fancyFunction(a, b)

    def doStuff(self, c):
        self._aab <<= c * 2

    def copyFrom(self, event):
        self.a = event.a
        self.b = event.b
        self._aab = event._aab

    def copy(self):
        e = Event(self.a, self.b)
        e._aab = self._aab
        return e
```

This implementation of `copy(self)` looks quite dirty now, and so does the overriden one from `MouseEvent`.

```
class MouseEvent(Event):

    # ...
    def copy(self):
        e = MouseEvent(self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d)
        e._aab = self._aab
        return e
```

How can I implement an easy, maybe recursive, *copy*-behaviour in this particular example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, isn't it enough that the `MouseEvent` constructor recursively calls the `Event` constructor?

If not, have a look at the [`copy` module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html).  It is based on [`pickle`'s state retrieval and restoration protocol](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances).  Using this protocol, recursive calls are easy.  You could of course just copy this basic design if you don't want to conform to the `pickle` interface, by I don't see any advantage to doing so.

**Edit**: It seems I failed to get across the message, and indeed my answer might be a bit vague.  So here we go with a code example using the suggested design:

```
class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self._aab = fancyFunction(a, b)
    def retrieve_state(self):
        return self.a, self.b, self._aab
    def restore_state(self, state):
        self.a, self.b, self._aab = state
    def copy_from(self, event):
        self.restore_state(event.retrieve_state())
    def copy(self):
        e = object.__new__(self.__class__)
        e.restore_state(self.retrieve_state())
        return e

class MouseEvent(Event):    
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        Event.__init__(self, a, b)
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
    def retrieve_state(self):
        event_state = super(MouseEvent, self).retrieve_state()
        return event_state, self.c, self.d
    def restore_state(self, state):
        event_state, self.c, self.d = state
        super(MouseEvent, self).restore_state(event_state)
```

Note that you wouldn't even need the `copy()` and `copy_from()` methods if you would simply rename `retrieve_state()` and `restore_state()` to `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()`, respectively, because after toding this you can just use the standard `copy()` module.  (And in the case at hand, you wouldn't even need to define `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()` at all, since the default behaviour is to save and restore all instance attributes.)

Comment: But, as I said, what if the `Event`-class owns private attributes ? Please take a look at the (added) example code. For the `copy` module, I'd again need to make a function `__copy__`, wouldn't I ?

Comment: @NiklasR: 1. The line `e._aab = self._aab` is redundant.  The function calls the `MouseEvent` constructor before, which in turn calls `Event()`, which in turn sets `e._aab` correctly, so there is no problem.  That's what I meant with the first sentence of my answer. 2. If you don't like this for some reason, implement `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()` on your classes.  Each of them can call the corresponding base class function.  The point here is to split up the copying in two parts, state retrieval and state restoration.  This makes it easy to ensure encapsulation.

Comment: "The line e._aab = self._aab is redundant" - It isn't, the user may modify `_aab` when calling `Event.doStuff(self, c)`. Actually I don't understand what this has to do with pickling, sorry.

Comment: @NiklasR: You asked for a design how to implement copying of instances while maintaining encapsulation, and I suggested a design to implement copying of instances while maintaining encapsulation – namely the design of Python's `copy` module, which incidentally relies on the `pickle` protocol.  The central point of this design is the separation of state retrieval and restoration, which makes it easy to use recursive calls.  You can either copy this design and define your own state retrieval and restoration protocol, or simply use the protocol that the `copy` module alreay uses.

Comment: Aha ! The code made me understand it ! This is really a good design. I will use it. Thank you